# How do I unwrap a generic type alias from a union type which makes the type alias more specific?

Tags: types, elm, algebraic-data-types, unification, parametric-polymorphism

I have type `Model`, which describes two possible states of generic type alias `ModelFields`. And I want to extract generic `ModelFields` record from an instance of the `Model` type.

```
type Model endValue stats
  = ShowEndValues (ModelFields Organism endValue)
  | ShowStatistics (ModelFields Rank stats)

type alias ModelFields object results =
  { results : List results
  , objects : List object
  , cellValue : results -> String
  , location : Maybe (Rank, Rank)
  }

getModelFields : Model endValue stats -> ModelFields object results
getModelFields model =
  case model of
    ShowEndValues modelFields ->
      modelFields 
    ShowStatistics modelFields ->
      modelFields
```

But Elm does not allow it saying for each case expression that

```
TYPE MISMATCH - Something is off with the 1st branch of this `case` expression:

55|       modelFields 
          #^^^^^^^^^^^#
This `modelFields` value is a:

    ModelFields #Organism# #endValue#

But the type annotation on `getModelFields` says it should be:

    ModelFields #object# #results#

#Hint#: Your type annotation uses type variable `object` which means ANY type of
value can flow through, but your code is saying it specifically wants a
`Organism` value. Maybe change your type annotation to be more specific? Maybe
change the code to be more general?
```

So my question is: how do I get `ModelFields` from `Model`? Or am I doing something fundamentally flawed?

UPD. Details of what I'm trying to model.

I have objects of type `Organism`. They are grouped into `Rank`s. My server does some pairwise analyses of `Organism`s, i.g. calculates `Similarity` and `Distance` between two `Organism`s. I'd like to display the results of these analyses in two tables on different pages, one page for `Similarity` analysis, and one page for `Distance` analysis. This means the table should be reusable to accept analysis results of any form.
On the other hand, there is one common pattern for these tables. They can be in two states:

1. Showing concrete results of pairwise comparisons (`endValue` in `Model`) between `Organism`s, so the table's rows and columns represent `Organism`s.
2. Showing statistical values (e.g. mean or standard deviation, `stats` in `Model`) between groups (`Rank`s) of `Organism`s, in this case the table's rows and columns represent `Rank`s.

Which `Rank`s or `Organism`s are shown depends on `location` field of `ModelFields`. User can click a button and I'd like to change the `location` in my `update` function. Potentially this navigation change can switch between `ShowEndValues` and `ShowStatistics` states. That's why I'm trying to unwrap `ModelFields` from `Model` constructors. I'm attaching a simple illustration in hope it helps to clarify.[image: table illustration]

Comment: This is [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What you're trying to do is not possible, and it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish at a higher level and why you've made the choices you've made to arrive at this, mostly because it's unclear why you need all these type variables. If you can explain this it might be possible to advise you on what to do instead, but otherwise it's hard to give an answer other than "Nope, won't work" and expand on the technical reasons for it, like Jan has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed not possible.

The `model` value in the `getModelFields` function will have type `Model endValue stats`. This means that it will either be `ShowEndValues` variant, containing a value of type `ModelFields Organism endValue`, or the `ShowStatistics` variant containing a value typed `ModelFields Rank stats`. The each branch of the `case` expression unpacks one variant and outputs the `modelFields` value.

Now, let’s try to determine the type of the `case` expression. We look at the types returned by each branch and try to find a type that encompasses both types (unify them). On a first sight, it looks promising: both values are in the form `ModelFields a b` so we will recursively try to unify each of the child types. Here we come across a problem – `a` of the first type has type `Organism` whereas the second one is `Rank`. There is not type that is both `Organism` and `Rank` so the compilation fails.

Note: As you can see from the error message, Elm actually tries to unify the types of the branches with the function result type. (I described the other direction because I think it is clearer to understand.) The direction followed by Elm also fails because it will recurse and try to unify a concrete `Organism` type with a generic `object` type, similarly to how we tried to unify two concrete types.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, Jan. So I got that this is not possible. I updated my question. Can you give any advice how to structure the models better?

Comment: If the data from both branches can be used for rendering to a table, the function should convert it to a common type the table can use, e.g. `Model endValue stats -> StatsMatrix`